# Calling other functions from a C++ constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

Is it safe to call non-virtual functions, including the assignment operator, from the body of a constructor after all member variables have been initialized?

Comment: Yes,constructor can other non-virtual functions. but safety or not depends on your code

Comment: Try initializing all member variables in the initialization list of constructor, then it is safe

Comment: @texasbruce: that's often a good way to keep track of things, but you can call other member functions from within the initialisation list so it needs a bit of self-policing and care.

Comment: @TonyD You can do anything if you are confident... even use the old C memory management code, but the OP want to be safe, so..

Comment: I can't think of a use-case for calling the copy-assignment operator from the constructor

Answer (score 1):

Yes, constructor can make call to non-virtual functions.

Make sure all members have been initialized properly before calling assignment operator otherwise object will be in an inconsistent state.

Use the "Virtual Constructor idiom" when you want to call virtual functions from constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can call other non-virtual member functions freely.  You can call virtual functions if the most derived base class provides an implementation you happen to want.

Indeed, before C++11 let one constructor call another, it wasn't uncommon for several constructors to call a support function to perform shared initialisation.

`operator=` can be called in these circumstances - the crucial thing is that any clean-up it might attempt before assigning new state will find sane values to operate on - for example, pointers set to `nullptr` so `delete` is safe.

Note that any exceptions from other functions you call that are allowed to cause the constructor to exit (i.e. not caught and suppressed) will prevent the object coming into existence - same as for exceptions thrown directly from the constructor function.